# How to prohibit Qt Creator to use specific include path automatically?

Tags: c++, c, qt, gcc

I use 2 different `GCC` versions on the same `CentOS` machine (included in OS one and custom one), and I don't want to replace system `GCC` with my custom one, I use custom one to build some software only.
The problem is that `Qt Creator` adds `/usr/include` to include folders automatically, so custom `GCC` starts to use system C++ includes and crashes with strange error messages like `error: '::memchr' has not been declared`. I don't have `/usr/include` anywhere in my `*.pro` file, so it looks like `Qt Creator` adds them itself.
How to prohibit `Qt Creator` project to use some specific include patches to allow compilation on machine with 2 `GCC` versions? When I use `Eclipse CDT` on the same machine, it works excellently, because Eclipse doesn't add anything itself and only uses include directories specified by me.

Comment: QtCreator has nothing to do with that, what kind of project are you using.

Comment: I use static library project. It is portable library that I compile on many OS and platforms, it doesn't contain anything QT-specific, however, I try to use QT Creator here just like universal IDE.

Comment: You have to edit the `.pro` file, google this `remove default include paths from .pro qmake project.`, and then specify your own include paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not elegant answer, if someone has better ideas, you are still welcome to post your answer and I'll accept it.
So, I added custom build step between `qmake` and `make` commands, and I use `sed` command in this custom build step to edit `Makefile` on the fly and remove extra includes. This solution works, however, it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CXXFLAGS += -nostdinc`.

This should do the following (excerpt from the manual):

> Do not search the standard system directories for header files. Only the directories you have specified
>   with -I options (and the directory of the current file, if appropriate) are searched.

Comment: It doesn't help. The problem is not in wrong standard includes. The problem is that `qmake` adds some includes explicitly with `-I` switch, and these includes cause error, and `qmake` adds them even when I set an empty value to `INCLUDEPATH`.

Comment: Are these files local to your project? Or, are they system related (e.g. installed apps/libs)?

Comment: `qmake` adds absolute path to my project to include paths, i. e. it generates command line option `-I/my/project/path`. This option causes compilation failure, probably some of my files names conflict with system file names, for example, `String.h` or `mutex.h`. When I copy build command generated by `qmake` and remove this option, it compiles good, it also compiles good with Eclipse CDT for example, because it doesn't add anything I don't want. And what is bad, `qmake` adds this include path even if I assign an empty value to `INCLUDEPATH` in my `.pro` file.